# Trying to verify jq command output equal string or string has more than one occurrence (AWS ELB instances state query)

Tags: bash, grep, jq

I'm trying to check that all instances attached to an AWS ELB are in a state of **"InService"**,
For that, I created an AWS CLI command to check the status of the instances.
problem is that the JSON output returns the status of both instances.
So it is not that trivial to examine the output as I wish.

When I run the command:

```
aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name ELB-NAME | jq -r '.[] | .[] | .State'
```

The output is:

```
InService
InService
```

The complete JSON is:

```
{
    "InstanceStates": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-0cc1e6d50ccbXXXXX",
            "State": "InService",
            "ReasonCode": "N/A",
            "Description": "N/A"
        },
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-0fc21ddf457eXXXXX",
            "State": "InService",
            "ReasonCode": "N/A",
            "Description": "N/A"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I've done so far is creating that one liner shell command:

```
export STR=$'InService\nInService'
if aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name ELB-NAME | jq -r '.[] | .[] | .State' | grep -q "$STR"; then echo 'yes'; fi
```

But I get **"yes"** as long as there is "InService" at the first command output

Is there a way I can get **TRUE/YES** only if I get twice "InService" as an output?
or any other way to determine that this is indeed what I got in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an informative sample of the JSON it's not clear what the best solution would be, but the following meets the functional requirements as I understand them, without requiring any further post-processing:

```
jq -r '
  def count(stream): reduce stream as $s (0; .+1);
  if count(.[][] | select(.State == "InService")) > 1 then "yes" else empty end
'
```

Comment: sorry' I forgot to attach the complete json output